# How to allow access for a pub ip of ec2 instance in security group (ingress rule in cidr block) for another instance using terraform?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have an Elastic cluster with three ec2 machines. I want to have access to each of the machines only from my IP address, but so that the virtual machines can communicate with each other(elasticsearch needs to communicate with kibana). When I allow all traffic (cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ])everything works good. I need to allow only my IP address and the IP address of the kibana virtual machine to have access to the elasticsearch virtual machine on port 9200. I tried different ways with Security group rules but it didn't work. How can I reference the IP address of my IP and kibana IP in cidr block?

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elasticsearch_sg" {
 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.elastic_vpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "ingress rules"
    cidr_blocks = [var.access_ip]
    from_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 22
  }
  ingress {
    description = "ingress rules"
     cidr_blocks = [var.access_ip]  #my ip  -- x.x.x.x/32
 #   cidr_blocks = ["aws_instance.kibana.public_ip/var.cidr"]
 #   cidr_blocks = [
 #          "${aws_instance.kibana.public_ip}/32"
 #      ]
    self = true
    from_port = 9200
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 9300
 
  }
  

  
  egress {
    description = "egress rules"
    cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
  }
  tags={
    Name="elasticsearch_sg"
  }
}
```

Comment: " but it didn't work" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin - kibana works only when i allow all trafic in ingress rule for elasticsearch instance. when manually add pub ip of kibana into elasticsearch_sg kibana still does not work("Kibana server is not ready yet"). but whem allow all traffic elasticsearch_sg, everything works good.

Comment: Is it AWS Managed Opensearch, or fully custom setup of ES on instances?

Comment: @Marcin  fully custom setup of ES on instances

Comment: You need a different port to be open for Kibana: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/access.html.